# Django point ImageField to an already existing image

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models

I have a model which has an Image field:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = "bar", blank = True)
```

I am downloading an image over the internet using urllib like this:

```
urllib.urlretrieve(img_url, img_path)
```

Now I want to point the Image field to this downloaded image saved as img_path. I have tried using `Image.open()` from `PIL` to first open the file and point to it and  `obj.image.save(File(open(file_path)))` using `django.core.files.File` but they don't seem to work. Is there an alternate way to implement this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simple set the `image` field to the new path and save the object:

```
obj.image = img_path
obj.save()
```

### Edit:

Note that `img_path` has to be relative to your `MEDIA_ROOT` setting.

Comment: Almost perfect. Just a little tweak was needed. I've written an answer with that tweak. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

`ImageFieldFile.save` takes the filename as first argument.

Try this out:

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open(file_path)
save_file_path = get_the_image_upload_to(obj)
obj.image.save(save_file_path, im)
```

Not sure if `im` is sufficient or if you should do something like:

```
from io import BytesIO

from PIL import Image

im = Image.open(file_path)
save_file_path = get_the_image_upload_to(obj)
file_io = BytesIO()
im.save(file_io)
file_io.seek(0)
obj.image.save(save_file_path, file_io.read())
```

Comment: I did try the first one before with no luck. Although, with another answer, I've found that with a little tweak you can directly specify the image's path. I've written an answer with the necessary tweak. Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 1):

With a little tinkering with [ilse2005's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1762988/ilse2005) answer. I found that setting the path directly works. The path must be relative to your media root, and it works like a charm.

So by that definition, this code works absolutely perfectly:

```
obj.image = os.path.join('bar', img_name)
obj.save()
```

Comment: I did that because it made the final fix, and if it matters much, I'm reversing the answer acceptance.