# How to display an avatar?

Tags: django, django-views

I made a function that generates avatars for users when they create a profile:

***users/models.py***

```
    def random_image():
        directory = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'media')
        files = os.listdir(directory)
        images = [file for file in files if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(directory, file))]
        rand = choice(images)
        return rand
    
    
    class Profile(models.Model):     
        user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        avatar_new = models.ImageField (default=random_image)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
```

For changing avatar i am using [django-avatar](https://django-avatar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#AVATAR_DEFAULT_URL)

There is a line like this (settings):

```
DEFAULT_URL = ("avatar/img/default.jpg")
```

I would like to display not a static image (default.jpg), but the result of the random function, which assigned the user an avatar. How can I make sure that the default url contains not a static image, but the result of the **field avatar_new**?

Tried it`DEFAULT_URL = Profile.avatar_new` error. Need help pls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

django-avatar has its own model for storing Avatars. You can try to add your own AVATAR_PROVIDER as they describe in their documentation.
Something like this might work:-

```
from avatar.models import Avatar
from django.core.files import File

class RandomAvatarProvider(object):
    
    @classmethod
    def get_avatar_url(cls, user, size):
        if not user or not user.is_authenticated:
            return
        avatar = Avatar(user=user, primary=True)
        random_image = cls.random_image()
        image_file = File(open(random_image, 'rb'))
        avatar.avatar.save(image_file.name, image_file)
        avatar.save()
        return avatar.avatar_url(size)
    
    @staticmethod
    def random_image():
        directory = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'media')
        files = os.listdir(directory)
        images = [file for file in files if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(directory, file))]
        rand = choice(images)
        return os.path.join(directory, rand)
```

Also you would have to add this into your settings:-

```
AVATAR_PROVIDERS = (
    'avatar.providers.PrimaryAvatarProvider',
    'avatar.providers.GravatarAvatarProvider',
    'app_name.where_provider_is.RandomAvatarProvider',
)
```

The random avatar provider must be **last** while you can chose which ones you want to keep above in which order.
Given your usecase perhaps you might want to remove GravatarAvatarProvider from AVATAR_PROVIDERS as it would always return some url.
**Edit**: add `'avatar.providers.DefaultAvatarProvider'` at the end of AVATAR_PROVIDERS and a AVATAR_DEFAULT_URL for unauthenticated users, or write some logic for them in the space where I am returning nothing.

Comment: thank you very much! This seems to be what you need! I'm going to try now. Please tell me if this code needs to be added to site-packages / avatar / provides.py?

Comment: Add it to one of your apps in some file as per your choice.

Comment: Added your code to avatar / providers.py. Launched, error: FileNotFoundError at /
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '5258.png'

Comment: Edited the answer, had just copied the random_image function previously

Comment: error: RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /
Avatar has no user.

Comment: and if for an authorized user: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 570: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: You are trying to get avatars for unauthenticated users? I'll make an edit for the charmap error.

Comment: Abdul Aziz, do you think, using the django-avatar library, is it possible to somehow make it so that when generating an avatar, not the avatar (picture) of the user's folder is saved, but to record the url of the picture that was assigned, thus, it pretty much saved memory. What do you think?

Comment: use [Django point ImageField to an already existing image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35795524/14991864). Instead of `avatar.avatar.save(image_file.name, image_file)` something like `avatar.avatar = path_to_image`

Comment: didn't quite get it, do I need to create a new field in the model?
Tried avatar.avatar = path_to_image - error

Comment: path_to_image must be a relative path from your media directory

Comment: I don't understand how to do this. Could you show how to implement this